# How to automatically download files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'd like to use visual studio to store in source control xml files coming from a server.
I have a request like http://server/query.aspx?FILE_ID=1234 that allows me to download an xml file. Those file are part of our development activities, that's why I'm looking for a convenient way of integrating those file in source control.

I'd like to have a project containing all the xml files I want to check-in in source control and add a pre-build command allowing to download the files, but I did not find any convenient way of doing it.

People have a tendency to forgetting to do it manually, and we have already seen all the possible scenarios: lost files, released version without the ability to know the exact configuration used, ... I'd like to automated this step so that it does not happen again in the future.

I'm sure there is a simple and smart solution, but I could not find it. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) in a pre-build action to fetch the latest version of the files. I can't think of a reason why that wouldn't work.

Personally i would consider finding a way to automatically commit those files to source control whenever they change on the server. I've never used tfs, but I assume there is a commandline-client which allows you to commit files in a scripted way. If you don't have any control over when the files change you could do this every N minutes on a machine which is always on.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a (powershell) script that does the fetching, and checkin of the file before your build starts. That's how we fetch external assemblies to be included in our build.

To get you started, take a look at these powershell functions for TFS interaction:
http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Programming/73/ (TFS 2008)